# Como calcular a diferença de horas?

Tags: java, android

`

```
package layout;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.marcosantonio.myapplication.R;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.joda.time.*;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import static android.R.attr.format;
import static android.R.attr.format24Hour;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Tela1Fragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private EditText    txtS1_C1, txtS1_E1, txtS1_C2, txtS1_E2, txtS1_C3, txtS1_E3, txtS1_C4, txtS1_E4, txtS2_C1, txtS2_E1, txtS2_C2,
                        txtS2_E2, txtS2_C3, txtS2_E3, txtS3_C1, txtS3_E1, txtS3_C2, txtS3_E2, txtS3_C3, txtS3_E3, txtS3_C4, txtS3_E4;
    private TextView    lblS1_F1, lblS1_F2;

    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private FloatingActionButton fab1;
    private FloatingActionButton fab2;
    private FloatingActionButton fab3;
    private boolean FAB_Status = false;

    //Animations
    Animation show_fab_1;
    Animation hide_fab_1;
    Animation show_fab_2;
    Animation hide_fab_2;
    Animation show_fab_3;
    Animation hide_fab_3;

    public Tela1Fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor

    }

    //@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tela1, container, false);

        final EditText txtS1_C1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtS1_C1);
        final EditText txtS1_E1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtS1_E1);
        final TextView lblS1_F1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblS1_F1);
        final EditText txtS1_C2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtS1_C2);
        final EditText txtS1_E2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtS1_E2);
        final TextView lblS1_F2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblS1_F2);
        final EditText txtS1_C3 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtS1_C3);
        final EditText txtS1_E3 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtS1_E3);
        final EditText txtS1_C4 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtS1_C4);
        final EditText txtS1_E4 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtS1_E4);

        final EditText txtS2_C1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtS2_C1);
        final EditText txtS2_E1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtS2_E1);
        final EditText txtS2_C2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtS2_C2);
        final EditText txtS2_E2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtS2_E2);
        final EditText txtS2_C3 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtS2_C3);
        final EditText txtS2_E3 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtS2_E3);

        final EditText txtS3_C1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtS3_C1);
        final EditText txtS3_E1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtS3_E1);
        final EditText txtS3_C2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtS3_C2);
        final EditText txtS3_E2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtS3_E2);
        final EditText txtS3_C3 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtS3_C3);
        final EditText txtS3_E3 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtS3_E3);
        final EditText txtS3_C4 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtS3_C4);
        final EditText txtS3_E4 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtS3_E4);

        txtS1_C1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                String currentTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                txtS1_C1.setText(currentTime);
            }
        });

        txtS1_E1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                String currentTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                txtS1_E1.setText(currentTime);
            }
        });

        txtS1_C2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                String currentTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                txtS1_C2.setText(currentTime);
            }
        });

        txtS1_E2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                String currentTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                txtS1_E2.setText(currentTime);
            }
        });

        txtS1_C3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                String currentTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                txtS1_C3.setText(currentTime);
            }
        });

        txtS1_E3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                String currentTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                txtS1_E3.setText(currentTime);
            }
        });

        txtS1_C4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                String currentTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                txtS1_C4.setText(currentTime);
            }
        });

        txtS1_E4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                String currentTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                txtS1_E4.setText(currentTime);
            }
        });

        txtS2_C1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                String currentTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                txtS2_C1.setText(currentTime);
            }
        });

        txtS2_E1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                String currentTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                txtS2_E1.setText(currentTime);
            }
        });

        txtS2_C2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                String currentTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                txtS2_C2.setText(currentTime);
            }
        });

        txtS2_E2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                String currentTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                txtS2_E2.setText(currentTime);
            }
        });

        txtS2_C3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                String currentTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                txtS2_C3.setText(currentTime);
            }
        });

        txtS2_E3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                String currentTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                txtS2_E3.setText(currentTime);
            }
        });

        txtS3_C1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                String currentTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                txtS3_C1.setText(currentTime);
            }
        });

        txtS3_E1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                String currentTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                txtS3_E1.setText(currentTime);
            }
        });

        txtS3_C2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                String currentTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                txtS3_C2.setText(currentTime);
            }
        });

        txtS3_E2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                String currentTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                txtS3_E2.setText(currentTime);
            }
        });

        txtS3_C3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                String currentTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                txtS3_C3.setText(currentTime);
            }
        });

        txtS3_E3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                String currentTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                txtS3_E3.setText(currentTime);
            }
        });

        txtS3_C4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                String currentTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                txtS3_C4.setText(currentTime);
            }
        });

        txtS3_E4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                String currentTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                txtS3_E4.setText(currentTime);
            }
        });


        fab= (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab1 = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab_1);
        fab2 = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab_2);
        fab3 = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab_3);

        //Animations
        show_fab_1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.fab1_show);
        //show_fab_1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplication(), R.anim.fab1_show);
        hide_fab_1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.fab1_hide);
        show_fab_2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.fab2_show);
        hide_fab_2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.fab2_hide);
        show_fab_3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.fab3_show);
        hide_fab_3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.fab3_hide);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (FAB_Status == false) {
                    //Display FAB menu
                    expandFAB();
                    FAB_Status = true;
                } else {
                    //Close FAB menu
                    hideFAB();
                    FAB_Status = false;
                }
            }
        });


        fab1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //long t1 = Long.parseLong(txtS1_C1.getText().toString());
                //long t2 = Date.parse(txtS1_E1.getText().toString());
                //long r1 = Long.parseLong(null);
                //lblS1_F1.setText(getTimeDiff(Date t1,Date t2, TimeUnit.MINUTES));
                String time1 = "16:00:00";
                String time2 = "19:00:00";

                /*
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                Date date1 = null;
                try {
                    date1 = sdf.parse(time1);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Date date2 = null;
                try {
                    date2 = sdf.parse(time2);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                long difference = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
                lblS1_F1.setText((int) difference);
                */
                //DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.class("HH:mm:ss");
                //SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

                //LocalDateTime dateTime1= LocalDateTime.parse("19:00:00", DateTimeFormatter);
                //LocalDateTime dateTime2= LocalDateTime.parse("16:00:00", DateTimeFormat);

                //long diffInMilli = java.time.Duration.between(dateTime1, dateTime2).toMillis();
                //long diffInSeconds = java.time.Duration.between(dateTime1, dateTime2).getSeconds();
                //long diffInMinutes = java.time.Duration.between(dateTime1, dateTime2).toMinutes();
                //lblS1_F1.setText(txtS1_E1.getText());
                lblS1_F2.setText(txtS1_E2.getText());
            }
        });
        //fab1.setOnClickListener(this);
        fab2.setOnClickListener(this);
        fab3.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        /*float t1=0;
        float t2=0;
        double r1=0;

        t1 = Float.parseFloat(txtS1_C1.getText().toString());
        t2 = Float.parseFloat(txtS1_E1.getText().toString());
        r1= (t2-t1);
        */

        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.fab_1:
                lblS1_F1.setText(txtS1_E1.getText());

                break;

        }
    }

    public static long getTimeDiff (Date time1, Date time2, TimeUnit timeUnit){
        long diffInMinutes = time2.getTime()-time1.getTime();
        return timeUnit.convert(diffInMinutes, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }

    private void expandFAB() {

        //Floating Action Button 1
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) fab1.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.rightMargin += (int) (fab1.getWidth() * 1.7);
        layoutParams.bottomMargin += (int) (fab1.getHeight() * 0.25);
        fab1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        fab1.startAnimation(show_fab_1);
        fab1.setClickable(true);

        //Floating Action Button 2
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) fab2.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams2.rightMargin += (int) (fab2.getWidth() * 1.5);
        layoutParams2.bottomMargin += (int) (fab2.getHeight() * 1.5);
        fab2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);
        fab2.startAnimation(show_fab_2);
        fab2.setClickable(true);

        //Floating Action Button 3
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams3 = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) fab3.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams3.rightMargin += (int) (fab3.getWidth() * 0.25);
        layoutParams3.bottomMargin += (int) (fab3.getHeight() * 1.7);
        fab3.setLayoutParams(layoutParams3);
        fab3.startAnimation(show_fab_3);
        fab3.setClickable(true);
    }


    private void hideFAB() {

        //Floating Action Button 1
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) fab1.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.rightMargin -= (int) (fab1.getWidth() * 1.7);
        layoutParams.bottomMargin -= (int) (fab1.getHeight() * 0.25);
        fab1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        fab1.startAnimation(hide_fab_1);
        fab1.setClickable(false);

        //Floating Action Button 2
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams2 = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) fab2.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams2.rightMargin -= (int) (fab2.getWidth() * 1.5);
        layoutParams2.bottomMargin -= (int) (fab2.getHeight() * 1.5);
        fab2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams2);
        fab2.startAnimation(hide_fab_2);
        fab2.setClickable(false);

        //Floating Action Button 3
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams3 = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) fab3.getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams3.rightMargin -= (int) (fab3.getWidth() * 0.25);
        layoutParams3.bottomMargin -= (int) (fab3.getHeight() * 1.7);
        fab3.setLayoutParams(layoutParams3);
        fab3.startAnimation(hide_fab_3);
        fab3.setClickable(false);
    }

}
```

`[image: layout da tela1]

layout da tela 1 onde pretendo subtrair o horario do fim para ser exibido resultado ao lado

Answer (score 4):

Costumo sempre ter um DateUtil nas aplicacoes para consultar esse tipo de coisa. No Java 8 tem novas abordagens. Mas segue ai, espero q ajuder.

```
public static int diferencaEmHoras(Date dataInicial, Date dataFinal) {
        return Math.abs((int) ((definirDatePrimeiroMinuto(dataFinal).getTime() - definirDatePrimeiroMinuto(dataInicial).getTime()) / 1000 / 60 / 60));
    }



public static Date definirDatePrimeiroMinuto(Date data) {
        if (data != null) {
            GregorianCalendar gCal = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
            gCal.setTime(data);
            gCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
            gCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

            data = new Date(gCal.getTimeInMillis());
        }

        return data;
    }
```

Comment: Obrigado vou experimentar !

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a api do JodaTime http://www.joda.org/joda-time/  e fazer algo assim:

```
Date minhaHoraInicial = new Date();
Date minhaHoraFinal = new Date();
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(minhaHoraInicial);
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(minhaHoraFinal);
Hours.hoursBetween(dt1, dt2).getHours();
```

Comment: Obrigado vou experimentar !

Comment: Sou principiante como encaixaria os 2 objetos txtInicial e txtFinal e lblResult para conter resultado no formato HH:mm:ss